# Including a module from another module

Tags: perl

This is a pretty basic requirement, but I don't really know the "right way" to get this to happen, even though I've gotten it to work in practice.

Say you have a Perl module that you know will be used by multiple programs within the same overall environment. That module needs to include a second utilities module, say in a subdirectory of the directory containing the first module. How do you make sure Perl can always find it?

`FindBin` comes to mind, but if your modules will be used by multiple programs in potentially different directories, you can't just say `use lib $RealBin/path/to/subdir`.

What I really need is something that says `use lib [location of module 1]/path/to/module2`. But I don't know how to do that, or whether that would be considered bad practice.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking, but if UtilModule isn't a submodule within UsedEverywhereMod, why is it in a subdirectory of it? And if it is, then you just use it like normal ie `use UsedEverywhereMod::Something::UtilModule;`

Comment: If you have several `lib` directories and you want to include modules from all of them, add all the directories to `PERL5LIB`, or run `perl -I lib1 -I lib2`, or symlink the needed modules for each program to its lib and use just that, or ...